# How to import XML using a Webpack loader WITHOUT automatic conversion to JSON

Tags: xml, webpack-4

Webpack 4's xml-loader automatically converts imported XML files to JSON.

By what means can I import XML ***without*** conversion to JSON?

The XML data is to be processed using an existing, application-dedicated XML parser.

To be clear, I definitely do ***not*** want the loaded result in JSON format.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out to be relatively straightforward, if not so well documented.

Basically, we rely on raw-loader, so (using pnpm to avoid module duplication):

```
pnpm install --save-dev raw-loader
```

in your webpack config file:

```json
rules: [
  { test: /\.xml$/,
    use: [
      'raw-loader'
    ]
  },
```

I'm going to use d3.js here (more declarative, hence concise).

The way you dissect your xml differs from application to application. Here I show the first step in processing a file in MusicXML format, with the score in partwise format.

Once you have the top-level tag, you can start burrowing down. Other xml formats have their own dedicated tags - which you will need to research and address in your code.

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import score from '!!raw-loader!./path-to-file.xml';
    
var parser = new DOMParser();
var score_as_xml = parser.parseFromString(score, "application/xml");

Could use d3.select(), as should only be one "score-partwise" occurrence:
var score_partwise_tag = d3.selectAll(score_as_xml.getElementsByTagName("score-partwise"));

if ((score_partwise_tag .. and so on.
```