# How to import local stored xml file into vue project

Tags: xml, vue.js

I installed new vue project to parser xml file to javascript. But I faced one error that I can't import local xml file into my project. I used axios method to get xml file. But how can I import xml file?

1)

```
   axios
   .get('static/sample.xml')
   .then(response => {
        parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
             console.log(result);
        });
   })
```

2)

```
    import sample from '../static/sample.xml';
```

First case code occurred one error.

GET http://localhost:8080/sample.xml 404 (Not Found)

And Next case occurred another error.

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

I am looking forward to your friendly reply.
Thank you for your considering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55288079/4050261 This will help you